# How to correctly address "ALERT: Iterations finished, maximum likelihood not found" in poLCA?

Tags: r, clustering, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, latent-class

I intend to use Latent Class Analysis on a large dataset with 12 response categories and approximately 50,000 observations.  I am getting an "ALERT: Iterations finished, maximum likelihood not found" warning when I fit models with more than two latent classes.  Can I conclude that the models beyond two classes are poorly identified as the log-likelihood is not exactly same? The model is fit with `nrep = 20` and `maxiter = 150` and most repetitions across all classes greater than two result in `llik` values which are in the range of [..,-243389.9, -243358.4, -243269.5, -243259.4, -243269.7,...].

I found contradicting information online and the reference textbook: In [this tutorial](https://opr.princeton.edu/workshops/Downloads/2020Jan_LatentClassAnalysisPratt_LCA_2020-1-14.pdf), they choose the models with 3 classes despite the said alert and in Collins, L. & Lanza, S. (2010) (page 95) they do not pick the 6 class model as the ML solution did not converge.  How seriously should I take this alert?

Any insights will help.

Answer (score 5):

Increasing the number of maximum iterations (`maxiter`) solved the problem.  This is because the number of iterations required increases as the number of latent classes increase.